# bokehjs with Angular: error while importing

Tags: angular, bokehjs

we are trying to import @bokeh/bokehjs in angular 10 and 11 as below:

```js
import * as Bokeh from '@bokeh/bokehjs';
```

However we are facing below issues while compiling.
[Compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X856I.png)

Error: node_modules/@bokeh/bokehjs/build/js/types/core/property_mixins.d.ts:115:30 - error TS1005: ']' expected.

115     [key in keyof T & string as `${P}_${key}`]: T[key];
~~
node_modules/@bokeh/bokehjs/build/js/types/core/property_mixins.d.ts:115:46 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

115     [key in keyof T & string as `${P}_${key}`]: T[key];
~
node_modules/@bokeh/bokehjs/build/js/types/core/property_mixins.d.ts:115:47 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

115     [key in keyof T & string as `${P}_${key}`]: T[key];
~
node_modules/@bokeh/bokehjs/build/js/types/core/property_mixins.d.ts:116:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

116 };

Below are the bokehjs and node version we are using

- bokehjs: 2.3.2
- node: 14.17.3

Could anyone please help us fix this and let us know if there is anything we need to do

Thanks

Comment: Would it be possible to include the compilation error inline so that if the image is ever taken down the full question remains in tact here?

Comment: Added errors inline

Answer (score 0):

Try to import just the required file from the build subdirectory.

Example:

```
import * as Bokeh from '@bokeh/bokehjs/build/js/lib/embed';
```

Refer this. I solved my problem using this:

https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/using-bokehjs-in-an-angular-app/5787/7

Comment: Suggested solution is not working for me.
we are trying to use bokehjs with angular 11/10 as a standalone without python. Could you please let us know which version of angular, node and bokehjs you are using